# Indexed array not printing elements in array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

My code below is trying to index every new entry to the array when the button is pressed. So automatically sort the element when the button is pressed.

```
          var arrayOfInt = [Int]()
    @IBAction func submitText(_ sender: Any) {
        if let text = enterText.text {
            if let number = Int(text) {
                var index = 0
                for num in arrayOfInt {
                    if num > number {
                        arrayOfInt.insert(number, at: index)
                        break
                    }
                    index += 1
                }
                print(arrayOfInt)
            } else {
                print("Please enter number")
            }
        }}
```

When printed this is what is coming out []. None of the numbers are printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially arrayOfInt is empty array. So it will never go inside this as the array is empty

```
  for num in arrayOfInt {
   //Whatever is here
  }
```

Your logic is also wrong for whatever you are trying to achieve.

Array has already **sort(by:(Element, Element) -> Bool) method**
You better write the code as follows:-

```
 var arrayOfInt = [Int]()
@IBAction func submitText(_ sender: Any) {
    if let text = enterText.text , let number = Int(text) {
            arrayOfInt.append(number)
            arrayOfInt.sort { return $0 > $1 } //Modify accordingly the order you want

            print(arrayOfInt)
        } else {
            print("Please enter number")
        }
    }
```

Comment: `arrayOfInt.sort { return $0 > $1 }` return keyword is redundant `sort { $0 > $1 }`. You could also just use `sort(by: >)`

Answer (score 0):

Your **arrayOfInt** variable has no elements, it's empty... so the **for** loop won't iterate over a zero index array, it would have no sense... that's why the code inside the curly brackets is never executed.

If you would have debugged your code with either a **breakpoint** or using a **print statement** this issue would have been shown by itself.

I would avoid using **if let** every time the **guard** statement could solve the same. Basically because it looks more readable and it's kind of the Swift approach... at the same time you are avoiding the [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)).

My suggestion would be:

```
var arrayOfInt = [Int]()

@IBAction func submitText(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let text = enterText.text else {

        print("Please enter a number")

        return

    } // guard

    guard let number = Int(text) else {

        print("Can't creates an integer value from the given string.")

        return

    } // guard

    arrayOfInt.append(number)

    arrayOfInt.sort() // From lowest to highest by default.

    //arrayOfInt.sort { $0 < $1 } // From lowest to highest using a higher order function.

    //arrayOfInt.sort { $0 > $1 } // From highest to lowest using a higher order function.

} // submitText
```